# How to bring application to foreground while running in background AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, background

I have created simple app that is warning me, from time to time, to do something. There is a sound that alarms me to do that particular thing and buttons to mark it as done, or to postpone action. It is running in a background normally. When time comes, I can hear a sound, but I cannot see and app in foreground to push buttons. How can I bring application in foreground programmatically instead of clickcin on icon at android desktop? I found many samples for java, but how to do it (if it is possible) in AS3?

Comment: i think, you must start your activity`s have button, near alarm codes ( when time comes )

Comment: I do not understand? what activity? Everything is OK when app is in foreground when time comes... but It can't be always in foreground. It have to be like an alarm you set in your Clock application, when it goes from running in background to foreground so you can click buttons in that app. In AS3 just don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: You'll need a native extension to do this; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934773/bringing-my-alarm-to-the-front for some discussion on the Android side of things.

Comment: Nice Brian, but that is for java, not for AS3...